# Bash scripting and using TAR to archive folders, how to grab the 5 most recent folders in a folder?

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, tar, aix

I have a script that archives a bunch of directories using tar, below is the snippet..

```
run_tar()
{
  clear
  echo "***"
  echo "This can take up to an hour, please wait..."
  echo "***"
  tar -X $BASE/synclive_exclude.list -cf - /usr2/docs /usr2/devel_backup /usr2/devel_config /usr2/devel_logs /usr2/devel_reports /usr2/devel_snapshots /usr2/doc-files | gzip > $DUMP_DIR/stage/usr2.tar.gz &
  wait
}
```

The problem I am running into is.. for one specific directory above.. /usr2/devel_snapshots the directory is large and consists of daily backups..

The folders within this folder are..

```
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     system         8192 Feb 01 11:15 201402011115
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     system         8192 Feb 02 11:15 201402021115
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     system         8192 Feb 03 11:15 201402031115
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     system         8192 Feb 04 11:15 201402041115
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     system         8192 Feb 05 11:15 201402051115
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     system         8192 Feb 06 11:15 201402061115
```

Is it possible to only grab the most recent 5 folders from /usr2/devel_snapshots in my tar command instead of the whole folder?

How would I go about making that work?

The OS is AIX 7.1 64bit

Thank you.

Comment: To list get a list of the most recent 5 folders you can `ls -tl | grep ^d | head -5 | awk '{print $NF}'` to list the files/dirs in a directory by how recent it is, grab all directories, take the top 5, and get those directory names :)

Comment: Another way to get the most recent 5 directories is to use **awk** `ls -tl | awk '/^d/{if (count<5) {print $NF; count +=1}}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like:

```
find /usr2/devel_snapshots \
    -type d \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    -mindepth 1 |
        sort -r |
        head -5 | 
        xargs tar -X $BASE/synclive_exclude.list -cf - \
            /usr2/docs /usr2/devel_backup /usr2/devel_config \
            /usr2/devel_logs /usr2/devel_reports /usr2/doc-files | 
                gzip > $DUMP_DIR/stage/usr2.tar.gz &
```

ls, sort and head will get the latest 5 directories and with xargs you can give the results as parameter to the tar command

Comment: actually.. it seems to fail now that it finished running.. # tar: 201402061115: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
tar: 201402051115: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

Comment: /usr2/devel_snapshots/201402061115 would have files and sub folders in that top folder.. would that be an issue?

Comment: I've updated my answer: now I'm using find so I'm sure that it'll return only the directories inside /usr2/devel_snapshots.